# Sakai SCORM Support

Tags: maven, scorm, sakai

I've downloaded and setup sakai binary 11.1 and got it running on my local webserver. However, I've logged into sakai and I can't find anywhere where I can upload a SCORM package into it.

Does Sakai have a built-in way to upload/view SCORM 1.2 or 2004 content?

Based on my googling, I suspect that the answer to that question is no. However, I did come across these instructions for adding SCORM support to sakai:

https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/SCORMPLAYER/Sakai+SCORM+player+installation+guide

I went to the provided [github repository](https://github.com/sakaicontrib/SCORM.2004.3ED.RTE/tree/11.x), checked out the code, and tried to build it. I got the following maven errors:

```
Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact org.sakaiproject:master:pom:11-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 13 -> [Help 2]
```

My best guess is that I need to have the full sakai 11 source code checked out in order to build the sakai SCORM support. I would really prefer to use the binary distribution from sakai instead of building my own copy of sakai. Is building my own copy of sakai the only way to get SCORM support? Or does this error message mean something else? Or is there a different free plugin which I could use? I do not have the ability to buy one of the SCORM cloud or rustici plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Sakai doesn't come with a SCORM player; however, several have been contributed and are in use.  Google for *Sakai SCORM* to find them.

The one we've used with Sakai 10 is [the one currently maintained by EDIA](https://github.com/sakaicontrib/SCORM.2004.3ED.RTE). Installing it with Sakai 11.x is easy, if you're already building Sakai from source: check out its source code from GitHub, switch to the right branch, add a line in Sakai's main `pom.xml` to point to it, and recompile Sakai - see the [installation instructions](https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/SCORMPLAYER/Sakai+SCORM+player+installation+guide) for details.  We have a permissions issue with it though: only `admin` is able to install SCORM packages and that appears to be due to a bug.